# Way(Optimized) to Implement following Scenario : Split Object in a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, optimization

Here, I need to split (clone) the original object based on the quantity. Whenever I am splitting an object, new BaseID is assigned to newly created Object.
**( Please Bear with me)**

**What I would like to achieve:**

Whenever an object (source) splits, a newly created object should be **added very next** to the source object (if source index is 0, then at index 1).

**This is how I am maintaining Object **

I am using a List to store the objects, that means newly created objects will be added at the end.

**What is the Bottleneck**

1) **Unknown Source Index**- Based on some filtering I am choosing the source and hence **I don't know the index of the source object**.

2) **Avg Number of split I will perform** - The Avg case will be 300 to 400 per second.

3) **Size of the list** - With current approach, I started with Object Count 300 (in a List), and after half processing, **it has reached 6 Million.**

For example: In input, I have the following list, note BaseID changes for each newly created object, Whereas Org_BaseID never changes and equals BaseID when the inputs are transformed into Objects.

**The input list is ordered based on some fields(for now Say Date), so the newly split Object will have the same value as the Original Object for Order by fields.**

[image: Input]

**One of the examples of the split**

Step1: Split Object1( BaseID: S1 having quantity 100) based on quantity, into say 80, 20. Please note Org_BaseID never changes, whereas New BaseID is assigned to the new object. Here is the resulting output.

[image: Step 1]

Step2:Split Object with BaseID: S5 based on quantity, say 15, 5. Here is resulting list.

[image: Step 2]

Step3:Split Object with BaseID: S1 based on Quantity, Say 70, 10.

[image: Step 3]

Step 4: If I order by the final List, I will get objects sorted based on Insertion order.

[image: Step 4]

Likewise, any Object can split any number of time given that quantity is greater than 0.

**Approaches I Have tried:**

1) Include Sort Order field, whenever a source object splits, update the sort order for all other objects. (If object with sort order 2 splits, 3 sort order will be assigned to the new object and hence update sort order of every object having sort order greater than 2 to current sort order value + 1), **It is updating all list i.e O(n)**.

[image]

2) Maintain Dictionary with key As Org_BaseID, Instead of updating all list, update sort order for Objects with specific Org_baseID.

[image]

**Is there is any other approach, which I can try?**

Thanks in Advance, and appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: I can't get the _order by updated list_, why it is `S7 -> S5 -> S6`?

Comment: Instead of adding the new object to the end of the list (array) and then do your custom sorting, could you not just insert it where you want it and then move the remainder items down a spot?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen- As I said, I don't know the index of the Object, so Insert means two operations, First to find the index, and second Insert which will re-create the list( internally), my record count is going up to 5 million, so it will prove costly over a long run. And one more thing I would be processing aroutd 300- 400 (Avg Case) insert per second.

Comment: @Alex- Since at last S1 splits, it created new Object i.e S7, so the output should be in the order of S1->S7->S5->S6=>S2=>S3=> S4 . whereas my list will contain S1=>S2=>S3=> S4=>S5=>S6=>S7 items and as order by follows insertion order, after  order by on the list it will give S1=>S5=>S6=>S7=>S2=>S3=> S4.

Comment: Is this CS homework? It looks like CS homework...

Comment: @Jordan- Nop,its not. Well, it's something which is eating my timesheet now a days.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should use a different container instead of a list. Sorting the entire list after each split is extremely inefficient. You need some way to access objects' indexing within the container. Some of the relevant code could help us give better suggestions.

Comment: @o_weisman- I thought of using **Linked List** ,  in order to add I will need to find the node first,  and again it would be O(n) and for such frequent add, it would not be a good approach.

Comment: It looks to me like you may need to use a tree. You have a single 'parent' at the moment but in reality you want to be able to split any node and preserve the order between adjacent nodes. Build a tree and then breadth-first search it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approaches I tried

**1) Allan S Approach- Insert an Object instead of adding.**

- It is a good approach for a smaller number of splits (up to 30,000), but as records are growing, it's started taking more time because of O(n) complexity.

**I Tried New approach**

-Instead of Inserting or Adding Split Object in the list (AVG 300 to 400 Add mentioned in the question), I Used  **Dictionary < String , Object >**  (to ensures O(1)) to track the splits.

**How it works**

- For Every split, Add the Object in the dictionary (BaseID of source Object as key and value will be new Object). One Object will split only one for current loop so key will be unique.
- Once splits over (One of the loops among Several), I will Loop through the main list and create a new list. For each Object in Main List, I will Add add it in the New list, and then will check is there any key in the dictionary for Given BaseID, if it's there then Add it in New list.
- Using this approach, I will recreate List only once, and it is working fine for larger input (better than my Old Approach i.e updating list for every split).

[image]

I will try to use Linked List and will check the performance.